# In JDBC, how do I know when I am at the end of my FETCH?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am following the example here

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-fetch.html

And then looping the following command manually

```
FETCH FORWARD 5 FROM liahona;
```

in java. I have the above in an infinite loop and would like to know how I detect I'm at the end of the data set so I can break the loop

Comment: What statement class, and query method (query,update,command) are you using to execute the fetch?

Answer (score 1):

You get an empty result set when running `FETCH FORWARD` and you are at the end of the cursor's total result set.  (This is described in slightly different words in the documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

In use JDBC for this kind of SQL - it's for postgres command-line only.

For JDBC, you need something like this:

```
ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from mytable");
while(rs.next()) { // next() returns false if there are no more rows
    int col1 = rs.getInt(1);
    String col2 = rs.getString(2);
}
```

Comment: It crashes I have a huge dataset

Comment: It should not crash anything - it only fetches one row at a time